# App dont show when implementation play-services-ads

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm facing a issue while implementing good play-services-ads, post implementation my app crashes and it doesn't appear anymore.

Here is my code :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


  android {

    compileSdkVersion 29

    buildToolsVersion '29.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dhsimple.game.blackjack"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

      implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try and attach the logs with OP.

Comment: When i delete implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1', app will run but when add it, app dont run and dont show any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I put this code in Manifest then app run.

....

```
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

</application>
```